Revert some but not all version edits to the original (target) version state in ArcGIS Pro 3.1
I have a version created by a job in Workflow Manager that contains edits I would prefer to not have to redo in a fresh version. I accidentally made edits to the shape of some features that I do not want to post to the default version. In Version Changes I can see which features have changed shapes but I cannot figure out how to delete those changes. Is it possible for me to delete them without deleting the whole version? I'm considering creating a new job and trying to create a conflict in that version, but I don't know how I would do that without still editing those features.
To be clear, I do not want the features to have changed shapes at all, I only want to keep edits I made to the feature class's attribute table and templates I created for the layer. Is this possible? The shape changes were very minor so when I compare the default and job versions on the map the polygons look nearly identical, but they have slightly different shape areas. I would be willing to manually edit the features to match the original shape but I can't figure out a way to make them match/trace the originals since they are in a different version.

There's no supported way to do this, but if you understand the versioning model, then an UPDATE of the adds table would work (or break the instance, or generate micro black hole to destroy the disk drive, or some other undefined behavior, so choose wisely). It is critical to understand that there is no such thing as a "feature class's attribute table". They're all just tables.

If there are not too many of these features, and if you don't mind a bit of manual work, you could add two layers, one with the old geometries and one with the new geometries.  Then simply copy the geometry from each old feature to the corresponding new feature (in the new version) using the 'Transfer Attributes' option (in the 'Modify Features' pane).
To access the old geometries, you may need to first access the DEFAULT version (or some intermediate version) and then export the features from the DEFAULT (or intermediate version) to a temporary feature class, then add this temporary feature class to use as the source for the geometries.  Then switch back to you current version with the new (wrong) geometries and add the layer directly from the new version.  This way you'll have two layers to work with.  One will be the temporary layer that you can use as the source of the correct geometries, and the other will be your current version with the incorrect geometries.
To transfer the geometry (shape) from one feature in the temporary feature class to the corresponding feature in the new version's layer without transferring any attribute values, you can use the Attribute Transfer option in the Modify pane.  To do this, follow the instructions in the accepted answer at:  Replacing one feature's geometry with another in ArcGIS Pro when all fields are different

Thank you, that was exactly what I needed!
